# File write incompatible types

Tags: java, path, incompatibletypeerror

```
List<Data> arrayListToFile = new ArrayList<>();
arrayListToFile.add(new Data("E30", "1985", ratingE30));
arrayListToFile.add(new Data("E36", "1992", ratingE36));
arrayListToFile.add(new Data("E46", "2000", ratingE46));
arrayListToFile.add(new Data("E92", "2007", ratingE92));
arrayListToFile.add(new Data("F80", "2014", ratingF80));

Path location = Paths.get("src/data.txt");
Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
try {
    write(location, arrayListToFile, utf8);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("The file could not be saved");
}

public static class Data {
    private String name;
    private String year;
    private String rating;

    public Data(String name, String year, String rating) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.rating = rating;
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error incompatible types:

```
java.util.List<com.company.Main.Data> cannot be converted to java.lang.Iterable<? extends java.lang.CharSequence>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? You might be getting error in `write(location, arrayListToFile, utf8);` method. Could you plz paste this method as well.

Answer (score -1):

The `ArrayList` class is an extension of the `List` class so if you are to use the ArrayList then go with it completely you initialization. It likely incompatible you can either specify the type of subclass in the constructor `new ArrayList<Data>();`

```
List<Data> arrayListToFile = new ArrayList<Data>();
```

or just initialize the object as ArrayList completely

```
ArrayList<Data> arrayListToFile = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Preferrable way is `List<Data> arrayListToFile = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: that is obviously how he initialize it